# index.xhtml resource not found in JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have created a blank .xhtml page in the WebContent folder of my JSF 2.2 application. I tried to run the app, but I got 404 - request not found.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Vijesti</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It has literally worked 5 minutes ago, and now it doesn't. It also doesn't work with `/faces/*`.

**Edit:** This is my index.xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:body>

</h:body>

</html>
```

It's located in the WebContent folder.

Comment: Maybe you deleted the page??? Please provide waaaaay more information...

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't, it's in WebContent...

Comment: You maybe have another problem with your application and thus it's not deployed on your server. Are there any errors during server startup? How do you try to call your index file in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your file to your list of welcome files. I assume your xhtml  is called index.xhtml. Try

```
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

Comment: No this is not needed... only if you WANT IT to be an index file. And even then it would not result in a 404